# Playwright - select child element innerText

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am trying to first select an array of page elements based on a common id.  Then loop through them to get the innerText of an h4 child.  Here is what I am trying:

```
    const headers = await this.page.$$("data-testid=my-custom-id");

    const rawData = await Promise.all(headers.map(async (header, i) => {
        return await (await header.$('h4')).innerText;

    }))
```

If I log rawData, I just see a bunch of:
[AsyncFunction: innerText]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I was almost about to copy paste the docs. You can follow this example (https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#lists) and close this question :)

Comment: Hi @hardkoded, thank you for your message.  In the lists documentation, the child they are selecting is also a tag (table tr).  In my situation, I want to get the h4 child of something i selected by a custom id and this "custom-id=a h4" doesn't work.  Am I just using a bad selector?  This is what sent me down the road of trying to perform a second select on the first result.

Comment: Oh, I see now:  I need custom-id=a>> h4.  Just for reference, though, is it possible to perform a second select on the result from a first?

Comment: Yeah. You can also get a locator inside a locator as you'd do with a `querySelector`.